# Loop video stream without resetting on repeat

Tags: vlc-media-player

In VLC, when streaming using an HTTP stream, the stream gets reset when the video loops. This causes applications like WiiMC to stop playing the stream altogether.

Is there a way to get the video to loop seamlessly without the stream itself being reset? If not, is there another lightweight application that can do this?

Comment: Have you enabled the `loop` option for the particular video file you're trying to loop?  (Ref: VLC Documentation, [Chapter 5.  VLM - Multiple streaming and Video on demand](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch05.html)).

Comment: That's videolan manager.

Comment: Upvoting, as I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the --sout-keep option https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help

> This allows you to keep an unique stream output instance across
>             multiple playlist item (automatically insert the gather stream output
>             if not specified)